Next.JS build is failing on Gitlab CI
In local I am able to build npm run build successfully.
On Gitlab CI it is failing for page.js:183:181489
When I checked here I was making a localhost:3000 API call.
Code Snippet
export default async function EnvironmentList() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/environment-list');
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
    }
    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch environments:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

Folder Structure
[!Folder Structureenter image description here]1
Local Build page.js:183:181489
[!Local Buildenter image description here]2
Next.js 14.2.5
   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully
   Linting and checking validity of types ...
   Collecting page data ...
   Generating static pages (0/7) ...
   Generating static pages (1/7) 
   Generating static pages (3/7) 
Failed to fetch environments: TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async f (/builds_dir/ags/ems/ui/client/.next/server/app/page.js:183:181489)
    at async v (/builds_dir/ags/ems/ui/client/.next/server/app/page.js:183:181717) {
  cause: AggregateError
      at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
      at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
      at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    [errors]: [ [Error], [Error] ]
  }
}


I found the reason why it was trying to call the API.
Due to server-side-rendering in Next.js. It tries to call the await function at the time of build. In my case I have used it inside the base component.
I still need to figure out how I can fix it.
